# Convert DataFrame into multi-dimensional array with the column names of DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array

Below is the DataFrame I want to action upon:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1],
                   'B': [2,2,3],
                   'C': [4,5,4]})
```

Each row of `df` creates a unique key. Objective is to create the following list of multi-dimensional arrays:

```
parameter = [[['A', 1],['B', 2], ['C', 4]],
             [['A', 1],['B', 2], ['C', 5]],
             [['A', 1],['B', 3], ['C', 4]]]
```

Problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847116/filter-data-iteratively-in-python-data-frame) where I have to iterate over the `parameter` but instead of manually providing them to my function, I have to put all `parameter` from `df` (rows) in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following list comprehension, which zips the values on each row with the columns of the dataframe:

```
from itertools import repeat

[list(map(list,zip(cols, i))) for cols, i in zip(df.values.tolist(), repeat(df.columns))]

[[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [4, 'C']],
 [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [5, 'C']],
 [[1, 'A'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'C']]]
```